# Problem with targets in XCode

Tags: xcode

I've got two versions of my iPhone app - FULL and LITE. It's the same project but I have two different targets for two different versions.

When I switch from one target to another and install it to my iPhone, everything gets messed up. At the first run I get only one application instead of two (even though they have different IDs). After that the icon changes to another version. At later runs, I get two different applications - one for lite and another for full version. But when I got it for the first time, they had the same icons!

If I try now to switch between version (install one of them using XCode), sometimes functionality gets mixed up - full version works like a lite one and vice versa.

I have to install a version for 10 times before it gets to work as I want it.

What's the problem? Is it something with XCode or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the separate targets each have their own Info.plist file, and that each target's Target Build Settings specifies the correct Info.plist File for that target, and that each Ibfo.plist file has a unique Bundle Identifier?